# Firebase app cannot be used in offline mode

Tags: firebase, progressive-web-apps

Recently I'm building a PWA using Firebase. All works well when I tried the offline mode through Chrome DevTools. But when I turn off my connectivity, turns out there's an error like this :

[image: Error Log]

The error keeps occurring in offline mode, although I already cache this particular file (with a different method I suppose)

[image: Cache list]

I already tried different approaches like :

1. Change the service worker caching strategy to CacheFirst, and StaleWhileRevalidate but ended up having the same error.
2. I also tried to add `matchOptions` parameter in the strategy to `ignoreVary`, `ignoreMethod`, and `ignoreSearch` as true. But what happen is my apps froze while checking the user log-in session and couldn't figure if there's any `currentUser` data (Although I already tried to set the Auth `setPersistence` to `indexedDBLocalPersistence`) or `currentUser` data is null.

Can anyone solve my problem? I'll appreciate any help.